# how to show all contents of a gridview cell resizing by height devexpress

Tags: winforms, gridview, cell, autoresize

I'm using a checked combobox reprository item for my gridview, and i add multiple words into cell use by checkedcombobox. I want to autoresize the row cell height to show all content.

working with winform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to handle the gridview's [`CalcRowHeight`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CalcRowHeighttopic) event and set the height you want in there.

You also may have to handle the [`CustomColumnDisplayText`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomColumnDisplayTexttopic) so that your cell has values put one below another.